# AngularJs 1.6 - Parent scope not accessible in directive 'link' function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, requirejs

I have hosted my sample app [here](http://publicapitest.azurewebsites.net/sof/)
I am trying to access MainCtrl variable into directives 'link' function but getting below error.

```
angular.js:14700 ReferenceError: testMessage is not defined
    at Object.link (TestDirective.js:12)
    at angular.js:1385
    at invokeLinkFn (angular.js:10545)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9934)
    at angular.js:10273
    at processQueue (angular.js:17051)
    at angular.js:17095
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18233)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18531)
    at done (angular.js:12547) "<test-directive>"
```

I have created angular app using requirejs.

```
    ------------main.js-----------------
    require.config{
       ///configuration here...
    });

    require(['app','angular','MainCtrl','TestDirective'],function(app,angular){
        angular.bootstrap(document,['MyApp']);
    });

    ---------------app.js-------------
    define(['angular','angular-resource'],function(angular){
        var ngapp = angular.module('MyApp',['ngResource']);   
        return ngapp;
    });

    -------------MainCtrl.js-----------------------
    define(['app'],function(app){
        app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
            $scope.testMessage = "Variable from MainCtrl";
        })
    });

------------------TestDirective.js---------------------------
define(['app'],function(app){
    app.directive('testDirective',function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'js/TestDirective.html',
            link: function(scope){
                scope.innerVariable = "Inner variable";

                //testMessage is defined in MainCtrl
                //I can access this variable in view i.e. TestDirective.html
                //But can not access it below
                scope.ourterVariable = testMessage;
                scope.testFun = function(){
                      ///cant access MainCtrl variable here....
                }

            }
        }
    });
});

----------------index.html------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <title>Heroic Features - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
    <script src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js" data-main="js/main.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      {{testMessage}}
      <test-directive></test-directive>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have hosted this app [here](http://publicapitest.azurewebsites.net/sof/)

After loading the page I am getting error in `<test-directive>` while accessing `MainCtrl->testMessage` As per my information while creating directive in a such a way, directive will inherit all the properties in `MainCtrl`.
Also, I am able to access `MainCtrl->testMessage` in directive's view but not in directive's link function.

Please help.

**Update 1:**

As per comment I have updated code to access MainCtrl variable to `scope.$parent.testMessage` Now I am not getting any runtime error but still, `scope.$parent.testMessage` is `undefined`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `scope` prefix in link function I was able to access MainCtrl scope variable.  My assumption, by default it refer to Parent scope was wrong :) 
Below is working code.

```
------------------TestDirective.js---------------------------
define(['app'],function(app){
    app.directive('testDirective',function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'js/TestDirective.html',
            link: function(scope){
                scope.innerVariable = "Inner variable";

                scope.ourterVariable = scope.testMessage;
                scope.testFun = function(){
                      ///To access ParentCtrl variable use scope
                      var pv = scope.parentVariable;
                }

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you please try this :

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <title>Heroic Features - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
    <script src="node_modules/requirejs/require.js" data-main="js/main.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      {{testMessage}}
      <test-directive ourterVariable="{{testMessage}}"></test-directive>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it didn't work.  Note that 'testMessage' is accessible in view of directive. However, I am not able to access it in 'link' function.

Comment: Just try scope.$parent.testMessage inside your link function.

Comment: @AnjD Thanks for your input.  I have updated my original question after incorporating your suggestion.  Still no luck..

Comment: @AnjD, I am able to access MainCtrl variables using scope.testMessage :)  Thanks for your help